# Clang: expression result unused with ternary operator

Tags: c++, clang, suppress-warnings

To print debug messages in my program, I have a that can be used like this:

```
DBG(5) << "Foobar" << std::endl;
```

5 means the level of the message, if the debug level is smaller than 5, it won't print the message. Currently it is implemented like:

```
#define DBG(level) !::Logger::IsToDebug((level)) ? : ::Logger::Debug
```

Basically `IsToDebug` checks if the message should be printed, and returns true when it should.  `Logger::Debug` is an std::ostream. This works with gcc and clang too, however clang generates expression result unused warnings. According to [this email](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2007-August/000166.html) this doesn't like to change either.

Prefixing it with `(void)` doesn't work, it will only cast the thing before the `?`, resulting in a compilation error (void can't be converted to bool, obviously). The other problem with this syntax that it uses a [gcc extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals).

Doing things like `#define DBG(x) if (::Logger::IsToDebug((x))) ::Logger::Debug` solves the problem, but it's a sure way break your program (`if (foo) DBG(1) << "foo"; else ...`) (and I can't put the whole thing into a `do { ... } while(0)` due to how the macro is called.)

The only more or less viable solution I came up with is this (assuming `IsToDebug` returns either 0 or 1):

```
#define DBG(level) for(int dbgtmpvar = ::Logger::IsToDebug((level)); \
                       dbgtmpvar > 0; --dbgtmpvar) ::Logger::Debug
```

Which seems like an overkill (not counting it's runtime overhead)

Comment: Is your usage of ternary operator correct? Where is the second expression?

Comment: It appears to be an unintentional use of the gcc ternary extension. DirtY iCE likely thought it would put nothing there but it is actually putting a bool there.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's a gcc extension (that clang also happen to support), see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals

Comment: ¤ First, note that the conditional operator usage with no second expression, is non-standard. A simple way to remove things depending on the debug level is to define `DBG5(e)` conditionally, so that it expands to nothing for debug levels lower than 5. For the expression, simply define in ordinary C++ a string creator class `S`, then use expression like `DBG5( S() << "blah " << x );`. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Joe looks like I have been so smart, that IsToDebug returns true when it should not print a message, I fixed the example. Since `<<` has higher precedence than `?:`, it will interpret it like `(IsToDebug(x)) ? : (Debug << "Foobar" << std::endl);`, it won't try to apply `<<` to a bool

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach I can't define the macro conditionally, since the level is specified runtime on the program command line. The problem with the string creation expression is that this macro is currently in use quite lot of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use ternary operator, as it is defined in the Standard, rather than compiler extension. To use the Standard ternary operator, you've to provide the second expression as well. For that, you can define a stream class, deriving from `std::ostream` which doesn't print anything to anywhere. Object of such a class can be used as second expression.

```
class oemptystream : std::ostream
{
     //..
};

extern oemptystream nout; //declaration here, as definition should go to .cpp
```

then

```
#define DBG(level) ::Logger::IsToDebug((level))? nout : ::Logger::Debug
```

Now if you use this macro, then at runtime, the expression would reduce to either this:

```
nout << "message";
```

Or this,

```
::Logger::Debug << "message";
```

Either way, it is pretty much like this:

```
std::cout << "message";
```

So I hope it shouldn't give compiler warning.

Comment: actually, it reduces to either `nout` or `::Logger::Debug << "message";` It would reduce to the two you mentioned if you had put parentheses around the expression in the macro. Having said that, using `std::cout` instead of `nout` for example, will also work, since `std::cout;` alone doesn't do anything. Using simply `false` instead of `nout` seems like to work too, although I'm not sure if it's standard. And even that doesn't produce a warning.

Comment: Note that you don't need to derive from `std::ostream`: just use an `std::ostream` which is in fail state, e.g. `std::ostream nout(0)`. Personally, I'm not a big fan of this because it still evaluates the expressions passed to the output operators. What you probably want is something along the lines of `!::Logger::IsToDebug((level)) || ::Logger::Debug`. This should have the correct precedence and prevent the expressions from being evaluated.

Comment: I think I will go with `::Logger::IsToDebug((level)) && ::Logger::Debug`. Is using `!` and `||` better than `&&`?